# Tail inequality for orthomartingales/martingale difference random fields

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, inequalities, martingales

It is known that if $(S_i= \sum_{j \leqslant i }X_i, \mathcal F_i)$ is a martingale, 
 then for each
 $
\beta>1$,  $\delta\in (0,\beta-1)$ and $\lambda>0$, and each integer $N \geqslant 1$, the inequality 
$$\tag{*} 
 \mu\left\{\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant N}|S_i|>\beta\lambda\right\}
 \leqslant \frac{\delta^2}{(\beta-\delta-1)^2}\mu\left\{\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant N}|S_i|>\lambda \right\}+
 \\
 +\mu\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb E [X_i^2 \mid \mathcal F_{i-1}]>\delta^2\lambda^2\right\}
 +\mu \left\{\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant N}|X_i| > \delta\lambda^2\right\} 
$$
takes place (see for instance Hall and Heyde *Martingale limit theory and its applications*, 
page 28). One can deduce the upper bound for $\mathbb E\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant N}|S_i|^p$
in Burkholder's inequality from (*).

Now, we are looking for multidimensional extensions. Below I present the so-called orthomartingales, but I will settle for any form of martingale difference random field.

Now, assume that $( \mathcal F_{n_1,n_2 })_{n_1,n_2 \in\mathbb Z }$ is a commuting filtration, 
that is, 
\begin{equation}
 \mathbb E\left[ \mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal F_{n_1,n_2} ]\mid \mathcal F_{n'_1,n'_2}\right]
 =\mathbb E\left[X\mid \mathcal F_{\min\{ n_1,n'_1\},\min\{ n_2,n'_2\}}  \right]
\end{equation}
for each integrable random variable $X$ and each $(n_1,n_2), (n'_1,n'_2)$. We denote 
$\mathcal F_{i,\infty}$ (respectively 
$\mathcal F_{\infty,j}$) the $ \sigma$-algebra generated by $\bigcup_{j\in \mathbb Z}\mathcal F_{i,j}$ 
(resp. $\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb Z}\mathcal F_{i,j}$  ).

Assume that the random field $(X_{i,j})_{(i,j)\in\mathbb Z^2}$ is adapted to the filtration 
$( \mathcal F_{n_1,n_2 })_{n_1,n_2 \in\mathbb Z }$ an that it satisfies 
$ \mathbb E[X_{i,j} \mid  \mathcal F_{i-1,\infty}]=X_{i-1,j}$ 
and $ \mathbb E[X_{i,j} \mid  \mathcal F_{\infty,j-1}]=X_{i,j-1}$. The process $(\sum_{i_1=1}^{n_2}\sum_{i_2=1}^{n_2}X_{i_1,i_2} )_{n_1,n_2\in\mathbb N^2 }$
is called an *orthomartingale*, see Khosnevisian's book *Multiparameter processes*.

---

**Question:** Is there (or is it possible to establish) an 
inequality in the spirit of (*) for 
orthomartingale random fields?

---

Such an inequality would allow to derive a moment bound for 
$\max_{i\leqslant n_1,j\leqslant n_2}|S_{i,j}| ^p$. This can be derived by an application 
of Doob's inequality and Burkholder's one dimensional inequality.

I am not sure that (*) holds for submartingales; therefore we cannot apply it directly 
to $\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n_2}| S_{i,j}|$ for a fixed $i\leqslant n_1$.

The main difficulty is that we do not have a useful total order on $\mathbb N^2$. Also, 
it seems difficult to identify what would play the role of the quadratic variances for $d=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, an extension of (*) is a way to establish Burkholder's inequality 
or [Nagaev's inequality](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1025814306357). For general ortho-martingale random fields, this is a difficult task.

However, if we assume that the random field is strictly stationary and the filtration completely commuting, then we can establish probability inequalities (see [Subsection 3.2](http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.00432)) and recover moment inequalities.